# Extract data from existing HTML with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) is great for complex client side JavaScript based web applications, but I also thinking about to use it for smaller simple JavaScript tasks.

For example I have a list with some items:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="1">Foo</li>
    <li data-id="2">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to add some buttons to the HTML which should filter and/or sort the list after some user input, which should be an easy task.

Is there any way to extract the data from existing HTML elements to use them with angular.js? The data need to be in the HTML, so search engine could also get a hold of whats

**Edit** for clarity:

The end result would be that the data from the `ul` list will be pushed into a model of the controller that handling the list. (`[{id:1, text:"Foo"}, {id:2, text:"Bar"}]`)
If I push more objects into the model, the list should display them.
If I apply a filter to the model it should filter the `li` elements.

Best case scenario would be something similar to this:

```
<div ng-model="data">
    <ul ng-repeat="object in data | filter:filterCriteria">
        <li data-id="1">Foo</li>
        <li data-id="2">Bar</li>
        <li data-id="{{object.id}}">{{object.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)? By adding a directive you've created via an attribute for example to the `UL` element, you could do what you wanted and look at the child elements, etc.

Comment: Question is not clear. What have you tried in angularJS?

Comment: Regarding search engine, have you seen this? http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: looks interesting @MarkRajcok but I still hope for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Apparently there is no way to this in a default Angular.js application.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in a project I'm working on. My solution was to add the data from the html to a variable in my angular controller and then hide the initial html. This method keeps the original list in the html for SEO, old browsers and users without javascript. It replaces this list with an angular generated one for other users.

A working example using your code is pasted below or you can see it at [this link](http://work.jtcraddock.ie/angular-example/).

I'm aware this is an old question so my answer might not be of help to the initial poster. My solution is aimed at anyone else who runs into the same problem we did.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.objects = [];
        $scope.init = function(){
          $("ul.data").hide();
          $("ul.data li").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var newObject = {
              name: $this.html(),
              id: $this.attr("data-id")
            };
            $scope.objects.push(newObject);
          });
        };
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="init()">
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="object in objects" data-id="{{object.id}}">{{object.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="data">
            <li data-id="1">Foo</li>
            <li data-id="2">Bar</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm giving it a +1 as this is the best response to the same problem I have. I wonder though, if this could be done with just angular itself, without including jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you could just use the angular.element().scope for the html element in question.

I use this method for certain interaction that can't be handled directly out of the box with angular.